# Perform function for another ViewController

Tags: ios, function, swift

I have a function in `ViewController` that I would like to perform from a UIButton in `ProfileViewController`. How would I do this? Below is the code I have tried.

Code in `ViewController`

```
func hideProfileButton (sender:AnyObject) {
    self.profileButtonOutlet.hidden = true
}
```

Code in `ProfileViewController`

```
ViewController.hideProfileButton(self)
```

Comment: Since the method you're calling is an instance method, you need to get a pointer to the instance of ViewController that you already have, or use a delegate protocol. You can't call the method on the class.

Answer (score 0):

**You can not directly perform one class's @IBAction from another class's UIButton**
Here you are dealing thing like owner and slave.
in storyboard/Xib file if you define that the owner of your viewcontroller is ProfileViewController then the UIButton of that view is only response to it's owners @IBAction.

You can have to Viewcontroller which have one owner like Two xib files with have same owner and then you can do thing like you say in question two different Xib files button call same @IBAction,br>

What you can do is...
1] Create an `@IBAction` in your `ProfileViewController` and call your `ViewController's method`
2] Create `delegate` object in `ProfileViewController` implement protocol like "btnClicked" and make `ViewController` to `response that delegate` by implementing it.
3] Create a `NSNotification` and make `ViewController` as an observer and call that notification from `ProfileViewController` (not preferable solution)